# Comprehensive reference for python standard library classes / methods

Tags: python, standard-library, pydoc

Is there a resource that provides quick/easy access to methods and their pydoc's for standard library classes?

E.g. I want to see what are the methods available on the Match class and the associated pydoc descriptions.  Starting pydoc -p 8888  is partially helpful .. but does not address this usecase.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you just looking for the python.org documentation?  http://docs.python.org/2/library/ for Python2.X and http://docs.python.org/3/library/ for Python3.X

Comment: I only see fnMatch there, where are the details for the Match class generated by re.match ?   It is not so clear how to use that reference for my purpose. thanks

Comment: The [MatchObject documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#match-objects) is pretty comprehensive. What are you missing? The [`re.match()` function description](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.match) hyperlinks you to that section.

Comment: @Martijn.   I did not know it were MatchObject, thought it were Match. Now to actually get to the final result, apparently need to click on 7.2 Regular Expressions and then browse the classes. It seems easy to you since accustomed to it, but not as much for me having worked with rubydocs that were more intuitive. Now maybe I have a handle on the process to find pydoc stuff from the lang ref.

Comment: I rarely, if ever, use `pydoc`. The Python documentation is organised per-module and excellently written, while generated documentation often misses the narrative provided in the Python documentation site.

Comment: You would expect 'pydoc re.MatchObject' to work, and way back in 2001 when pydoc was born that _did_ work.

https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2001-January/011538.html

But it doesn't any more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Specifically for your case, help on the `re.MatchObject` can be found at 
http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#match-objects for Python 2.x or http://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#match-objects for Python 3.x.

Additionally, as Mark writes, you can call `help` on the interactive console.  If you don't know how to get to the interactive console, you can just call `python` or `python.exe` from the command line without any arguments.

Since you are looking for help on a match object, you can call

```
>>> m = re.match('a','a')  #example match command
>>> help(m)
```

Comment: Ok, the language reference is further down on the page on http://docs.python.org/2/library/  . Then have to click on regular expressions. This is not as fast as the ruby online ref, but usable. If you feel this were reasonable question pls upvote. thx

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
>>> import re.match
>>> help(re.match('', ''))
```

from the interactive console.

- Edited to add your specific example.

Comment: What is syntax for this ?  I tried help('re.Match')
no Python documentation found for 're.Match'

Comment: Don't quote it, pass in the actual object.

Comment: help() takes actual python objects so help(Match), assuming you did from re import Match

Comment: You cannot; it's an internal C implementation. It's one of the (few) warts in the std library. You can get an instance with `re.match('', '')`.

Comment: `re.match` returns a `_sre.SRE_Match` object, which can't be imported.